# setting the origin to the center with an orthographic projection

Tags: iphone, android, opengl-es

Im trying to set it in the center instead of the default lower left of my screen. How could i accomplish this? I know it involves setting up the glOrth method but havent been able to figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct setting was:

```
    gl.glOrthof(-width*.5f, width*.5f,-height*0.5f, height*0.5f,near,far);
```